# Fixing chatbot order acceptance rules based on LangChain and OpenAI embeddins

Tags: openai-api, embedding, py-langchain

I had created a bot to answer questions about a product using LangChain and OpenAI embeddings, but it was not able to provide good answers to the questions. What can I do to improve this?
The bot should have asked for the user's name, phone number, and quantity of the product if they wanted to purchase the product. If the user provided their information, the bot should have said that operators would contact them shortly.
Sometimes it was doing this, but other times it was just saying that the product could be purchased from our online store.
The chatbot should also answer the user's question and ask them a question to ask for the user's information
I have included this text in the file honeymoon5.pdf so that the chatbot can ask questions from the users
If the product indicates to buy a HoneyMoon product or purchase
if you want to get:

1. asks the benefit for its name
2. Asks for the phone
3. Determines the delivery address
4. Determines which one to buy (canned or packaged, quantity)

This is the program I wrote:

```py
pdf_path = "Data/HoneyMoon55.pdf"
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_path)
raw_text = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    raw_text += page.extract_text()

cleaned_text = raw_text.replace("\n", " ").strip()
splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(separator="\n", chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=350)
texts = splitter.split_text(cleaned_text)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
docsearch = FAISS.from_texts(texts, embeddings)
chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff")
context = []
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    global context
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_name = message.from_user.first_name

    history = {"context": context}
    prompt = history
    prompt = json.dumps(prompt)
    print(prompt)

    if len(context) > 10:
        context = context[-1]
    query = f"bot role:{BOT_ROLE} Language:{language} Pervious text:{prompt}  query:{message.text}"
    context.append(query)

    user_file = os.path.join(CHAT_LOG_DIR, f"{user_name}_{user_id}.txt")
    if not os.path.exists(CHAT_LOG_DIR):
        os.mkdir(CHAT_LOG_DIR)

    docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query, k=1)
    result = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
    bot_response = f'answer:{result}'
    context.append(bot_response)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)

    with open(user_file, "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{user_name}: {query}\n")
        f.write(f"Bot: {result}\n")

    chat_log.append((query, result))
```